# Access meta data information in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, metadata

I want to access the meta data information in iphone application as lets say user enter url in textfield like. yahoonews.com

then it should return me meta data information in NSString.

```
 YAHOO NEWS
<head>
<script>var t_headstart=new Date().getTime();</script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Passenger Falls Out of Plane Off Florida Coast - Yahoo News</title>
```

I want to get the  title  and meta data description in NSString this is just dummy html but i want directly from the url which is entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the page source using this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

And then parse the string to get the required. Enjoy :)

Comment: i did not get the parse the string to get required mean

Comment: means you will get the complete source in a string and you can extract the required substring from it.